# Css floating issues

Tags: css, css-float

Hello i am having a few difficulties with my floating containers, i have 2 containers, 1 left and 1 right. The left container floats to the left. However if the left container is 200px then the right container should not adjust to 200 px as well because obviously it's a floating element. However in my situation it adjusts and i don't know how to fix that.[image]

The blue container is the wrapper, then you have 2 red containers, however you can see that the right container is adjusting its height to the left one which it shouln't do.

Some code i am using:

```
<div class="mcsf_posts">
            {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="mcsf_post">
                <div class="mcsf_post_author">
                    <div class="mcsf_post_author_image">
                        <img src="{{ asset('/bundles/maximcms/images/blank.gif') }}" data-src="http://minotar.net/avatar/{{ post.createdBy.username }}/45.png" alt="mc the mass logo"/>
                        <noscript>
                            <img src="http://minotar.net/avatar/{{ thread.createdBy.username }}/45.png" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="{{ post.createdBy.username }}" alt="{{ post.createdBy.username }}">
                        </noscript>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mcsf_post_author_info">
                        <p class="mcsf_post_author_name">{{ post.createdBy.username }}</p>
                        <p class="mcsf_post_author_title">Moderator</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mcsf_post_content">
                    <div>
                        {{ post.text|raw }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mcsf_post_content_lowerbar">
                        <span class="mcsf_post_createdOn">{{ post.createdOn|date('M j \, Y H:i:s') }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.mcsf_post {

}
.mcsf_post + .mcsf_post {
    margin-top:10px;
}
.mcsf_post_author {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.mcsf_post_content{
    margin-left: 131px;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    height: auto!important;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *ADJUST* here

Comment: It just takes on the same height as the left container which it's not supposed to do

Comment: If you posted the CSS, it might help to see what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I updated my original post with the css

Answer (score 0):

this [link](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) should be of assistance it as an example that demonstrates the same scenario. However, just applying  floats to both elements should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found and solved the problem, there was a cleafix at the parent element and because of that it made the right container have the same height as the left + it's contents. Removing the clearfix and adding a clear:left at the correct position solved my problem